# Android - Webview loadURL issue

Tags: android, webview

How do I load `webview` with `WebView.loadUrl` if there is a space in `fileName`?
Example:

```
file:///data/data/com.infor.android.eam.tablet/cache/Sheis HD 202_2014011.pdf
```

does not work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Uri encodedPath = Uri.parse(path);

webView.loadUrl(encodedPath);
```

alternatively, in every location where there is a space put %20 instead of the space

Comment: I have used Uri.parse, and the path comes with %20 like file:///data/data/com.infor.android.eam.tablet/cache/Sheis%20HD%20202_2014011.pdf..but still it would not work...please help

Comment: does this file exist on the device? do you have permission to read it?  does it load if the name doesnt have spaces in it?

Comment: yes the file exist in data/data/com.infor.android.eam.tablet/cache....I  copied that file on desktop and opened in google chrome and it opened fine

Comment: not in desktop, in the device, if you change its file name to be without spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 URL oracle = new URL(uri);
  URI url=newURI(oracle.getProtocol(),oracle.getUserInfo(),oracle.getHost(),oracle.getPort(),oracle.getPath(),oracle.getQuery(),oracle.getRef());

                  oracle=url.toURL();
```

place Your file url in variable uri.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url=file:///data/data/com.infor.android.eam.tablet/cache/Sheis HD 202_2014011.pdf;
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +url);
```